# groups.get(client_group_name, []) in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have ansible-playbok yaml file that have one condition and one delegation

```
when: not delegate_facts_host | bool or inventory_hostname in groups.get(client_group_name, [])


delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
delegate_facts: True
with_items: "{{ groups['all'] | difference(groups.get('clients', [])) }}"
```

I do not understand this line. when I print

```
delegate_facts_host
```

It shows True even if I set

```
  vars:
    delegate_facts_host: False
```

the most confusing part is

```
groups.get(client_group_name, [])
```

I search but I do not understand it at all

Comment: the code is not from a playbook but from a task, or am I mistaken?

Comment: it is from ceph-ansible playbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a good Ansible here...

1. `groups['all']` is a list of all hosts (group 'all' contains all hosts, groups is a magic variable).
2. `groups.get('clients', [])` is a mix of Ansible and Python. Groups is a magic variable (which is a python dictionary!), so we use python 'get' method to make `groups['clients']` with default value set to empty list (`[]`). See [1]
3. `|difference` is Jinja filter which takes list from the left part (`groups['all']`) and subtract a list from the right (`groups.get('clients', [])`). The result is a 'list of all hosts whose are not in clients group'.
4. `with_items` iterates over this list.
5. `delegate_to: {{ item }}` is run code on each host from this list.
6. when: `not delegate_facts_host | bool` uses bool fiter (converts strings 'yes', 'no', etc into bool value) - task is run if delegate_facts_host set to 'no'  OR if `inventory_hostname in groups.get(client_group_name, [])` - second part checks if host is in the group with name 'client_group_name`.

Basically, it says 'run this with data from non-clients on all clients' (run on all clients but delegate to all non-clients). It's neat and concise, but not a beginner friendly, yes.

[1] 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

> get(key[, default])
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this
>   method never raises a KeyError.

Comment: ops, I've missed it. Updating now.